# Error on Scafolding EF Core 1.0 to Existing Db

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ef-code-first, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Today I installed latest version of ASP.NET Core 1.0 and VS2015 Update 3 (released on June 27) on Win 7. And followed an MS Article and got the following error on [this step of the article](https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#reverse-engineer-your-model):

```
Unable to find expected assembly attribute named DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute in provider assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. This attribute is required to identify the class which acts as the design-time service provider factory.
```

My command is as follows:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=MyComputerName\SQL2012;Database=northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;" -OutputDir ".\Models"  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
```

**project.json File one section**

```
"tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

On win 8.1 with SQL Express 2014, with the above release of ASP.NET Core and VS2015 Update 3, I can successfully follow all the steps in the above article without any error.

Answer (score 1):

Someone helped me to point out my mistake. Since I'm using SQL Server, the last parameter in my `Scaffold-DbContext` command should be `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. Following works:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=MyComputerName\SQL2012;Database=northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;" -OutputDir ".\Models"  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```